# Web-mode javascript indentation for “if” and “for”

Tags: indentation, web-mode

When writing Javascript, I always put curly brackets after `if` in a new line, like this:

```
if(a == 0)
{
    ....
```

But when I do that in web-mode, the default is like this:

```
if(a == 0)
    {
        ....
```

Is there a way to fix this?

BTW the same goes with `for`, but not with function definition.  Version information:

```
versions: emacs(25.1) web-mode("14.0.13”)
```

I don’t have this problem in the plain javascript-mode.

Here’s a minimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script>
   var a = 0;
   if(a == 0)
       {
           a = 1;
       }
  </script>
</html>
```

UPDATE:

As @Scott Weldon in the comments suggested, I tried several things:

- I updated web-mode to 14.0.19.  Same problem.
- I tried using web-mode in a clean Emacs. Same problem.  What I did was:

  1. I ran `emacs -Q`.
  2. Then I `M-x load-library RET ~/.emacs.d/elpa/web-mode-20160717.1201/web-mode.el` to load web-mode.
  3. I then tried the minimal example.

Comment: Does this issue still occur when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, please try to [bisect your init file](//meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/a/204/675). Also, what version of `web-mode` are you using? (Post the output of `M-x web-mode-debug`.)

Comment: @ScottWeldon, if I use `emacs -Q`, it would not find web-mode package.  Versions: `versions: emacs(25.1) web-mode("14.0.13”)`.

Does the indentation for cc-mode affect web-mode javascript?  The only configuration I have for web-mode is a `(setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)`.  Also if I just use plain javascript-mode, it doesn’t have this problem.

Comment: I should have clarified: start with `emacs -Q` and then do `M-x load-library RET /path/to/web-mode.el RET`.

Comment: Also, please [edit] any new details into your post so that other users can easily see the information without digging through the comments.

Comment: The version of `web-mode` that I am using is `14.0.19`, so maybe try upgrading. I'm also using Emacs 24.4, so maybe there's an issue only affecting Emacs 25.

Comment: @ScottWeldon, thank you for all the suggestions.  Sadly they didn’t work on me.  Please see my update for details.

Comment: Oops, I messed up on my first test; I am actually able to reproduce the issue. Let me see if I can find the solution.